# FFmpeg can't stream AAC files from stdin?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm having trouble getting FFmpeg to convert an AAC file to HLS chunks:

```
cat file.m4a | ffmpeg -y -i pipe:0 -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 0 -map 0:0 -f segment -segment_time 10 -segment_list ./segments.m3u8 -segment_format mpegts -vn ./segment_%03d.ts
```

This is being executed in Node.js in a Lambda function (streaming from AWS S3 - the command line above is just for testing purposes).

The relevant error I get is:

```
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (aac (native) -> mp3 (libmp3lame))
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x397e640] stream 0, offset 0x28: partial file
pipe:0: Invalid data found when processing input
```

If I do `-i file.m4a`, it works perfectly fine. It's not a deal-breaker, but it would be nice to be able to use stdin, which works OK for MP3 and WAV files.

Comment: It’s not the codec. It’s the container. A .aac (adts) can be piped. A m4a/mp4 can not.

Answer (score 4):

The `m4a` is a MPEG-4 Part 14 (MP4) container and not raw AAC and might require seeking. You might be able to pipe it if the `moov` atom is placed at the beginning of the file (ie. when using faststart) but you're better off with the input option.

Comment: Same issue here.
Works from file: `ffmpeg -i file.m4a -ss 0 -to 10 -acodec copy /tmp/cut_file.m4a`
Get broken reading from pipe:
`cat file.m4a |ffmpeg -i pipe:0 -ss 0 -to 10 -acodec copy /tmp/cut_file.m4a`

How can I handle this pipe issue and why ffmpeg acts different with pipes and files?

Comment: @remort `-ss` seeks and pipe input doesn't support seeking

Comment: aergistal, thank you for explanation. Where I can read about it more ?
but... `-ss` works with pipes when i send mp3 or flac or ogg 'bytes' to the input pipe.

Comment: @remort As noted in the answer `m4a` is not a raw stream, it's a MP4 container and seeking is dependent on the presence of the `moov` atom which could be positioned at the end of the file.